# Performance issues with `AVAssetWriter`

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm trying to build a Camera app that records Video and Audio buffers (`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`) to an mp4/mov file using `AVAssetWriter`.

When creating the Recording Session, I noticed that it blocks for around 5-7 seconds before starting the recording, so I dug deeper to find out why.

This is how I create my AVAssetWriter:

```swift
let assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: tempURL, fileType: .mov)
let videoWriter = self.createVideoWriter(...)
assetWriter.add(videoWriter)
let audioWriter = self.createAudioWriter(...)
assetWriter.add(audioWriter)
assetWriter.startWriting()
```

There's two slow parts here in that code:

1. The `createAudioWriter(...)` function takes ages!

   This is how I create the audio `AVAssetWriterInput`:

   ```swift
   // audioOutput is my AVCaptureAudioDataOutput, audioInput is the microphone
   let settings = audioOutput.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov)
   let format = audioInput.device.activeFormat.formatDescription

   let audioWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio,
                                        outputSettings: settings,
                                        sourceFormatHint: format)
   audioWriter.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
   ```

   The above code takes up to **3000ms** on an iPhone 11 Pro!

   When I remove the recommended settings and just pass `nil` as `outputSettings`:

   ```swift
   audioWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio,
                                    outputSettings: nil)
   audioWriter.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
   ```

   ...It initializes almost instantly - something like **30** to **50ms**.
2. Starting the `AVAssetWriter` takes ages!

   Calling this method:

   ```swift
   assetWriter.startWriting()
   ```

   ...takes takes **3000** to **5000ms** on my iPhone 11 Pro!

Does anyone have any ideas why this is so slow? Am I doing something wrong?

It feels like passing `nil` as the `outputSettings` is not a good idea, and `recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter` should be the way to go, but 3 seconds initialization time is not acceptable.

Here's the full code: [`RecordingSession.swift` from react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/main/package/ios/Core/RecordingSession.swift). This gets called [from here](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/deb3c41ee0a55e64cbb83ead912ccdd53d10988f/package/ios/Core/CameraSession%2BVideo.swift#L14-L161).

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

**EDIT:**

These are the `recommendedVideoSettingsForAssetWriter` settings I get:

```
["AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey": {
    AllowFrameReordering = 1;
    AllowOpenGOP = 1;
    AverageBitRate = 47848572;
    BaseLayerFrameRate = 15;
    ExpectedFrameRate = 60;
    MaxAllowedFrameQP = 41;
    MaxKeyFrameIntervalDuration = 1;
    MinAllowedFrameQP = 15;
    MinimizeMemoryUsage = 1;
    Priority = 80;
    ProfileLevel = "HEVC_Main_AutoLevel";
    RealTime = 1;
    RelaxAverageBitRateTarget = 1;
},
 "AVVideoWidthKey": 2160,
 "AVVideoCodecKey": hvc1,
 "AVVideoHeightKey": 3840]
```

(video initializes in ~10ms)

And these are the `recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(..)` I get:

```
["AVEncoderQualityForVBRKey": 91,
 "AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey": 96000,
 "AVEncoderBitRateStrategyKey": AVAudioBitRateStrategy_Variable,
 "AVFormatIDKey": 1633772320,
 "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 1,
 "AVSampleRateKey": 44100]
```

(audio initializes in ~1500-3000ms)

Note that subsequent calls are faster. I am also changing the `AVAudioSessionCategory` while configuring the audio AVAssetWriter, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

**EDIT 2**:

I just found out that it takes so long to initialize the audio `AVAssetWriter` because I start the audio `AVCaptureSession` while I initialize the audio `AVAssetWriter`:

```swift
audioQueue.async { // <-- should be async/non-blocking
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                                              options: [.mixWithOthers,
                                                        .allowBluetoothA2DP,
                                                        .defaultToSpeaker,
                                                        .allowAirPlay])
  audioCaptureSession.startRunning() // <-- this takes 1.5-3s
}
let audioWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(...) <-- w/ recommended settings
```

Apparently the `AVAssetWriter` also waits for the `AVAudioSession`? Maybe there's some internal Mutex going on, because I'm 100% sure that this should run in parallel...

Either way - I can't really start the audio session in advance because I don't want to introduce that mini audio stutter if the user starts the app and has music playing, and I know that Snapchat is also achieving that on the fly - any thoughts?

Comment: No you don't want `nil` `outputSettings`. Can you share the `outputSettings` you are using?

Comment: @GordonChilds yup, `nil` means just unfiltered raw audio right? Updated my original post with the options that got resolved.

Comment: I think my issue is just a debug/LLDB issue - it does not happen in release builds..